# What is auto generating the assets folder in development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am using rails 3.2.6 and my development.rb file has

```
# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

and for some reason evertime i look in my public folder I have an assets folder that keeps appearing....I keep deleting it but it keeps reappearing ....is there a way to stop this

The main problem is the assets are being declared twice, once in the assets folder and once in the public folder which is an exact duplicate...this is messing things up for me

Comment: Are you running precompile on your development machine?

Comment: I dont think so but i did once...is there a way to check this. In my development.rb i dont have anything set to do that. I did run the precomplile once to test something. Could that possilby be the issue

Answer (score 0):

in application.rb

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

Comment: will that effect production because in production i am precompling my assets

Comment: plus i get this error when i do that  The less-rails plugin requires the asset pipeline to be enabled

Comment: Yes that will effect production...  Sounds like you are precompiling the assets locally

Answer (score 0):

Solved....I was my guard file compiling the assets

I commented out

```
 guard 'rails-assets' do
   watch(%r{^app/assets/.+$})
   watch('config/application.rb')
 end
```

And all is well